# Adding Item decoration to a groupie expandable group

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is it possible to add a footer item decoration to the groupie expandable item, Such that when the group is expanded the decoration is at the bottom of the child items, and when not expanded is at the bottom of the header.

[image]

Comment: are you using [groupie](https://github.com/lisawray/groupie)?

Comment: @user158 yes i am